# The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl

I have two projects. One is WCF project and the other one is client. The WCF project is hosted by IIS which uses SSL. 
I created self-signed certificate by IIS And bind the certificate to URL:localhost:4435/Service1.svc. When use IE open the site, it shows 'The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.'
The certificate is already exported in the "Trust Root Certification Authorities".
Via Visual Studio, I can add service reference for client，but when I call the service, it show me the "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'localhost:4435'."
I am in trouble, wish someone to help me,
Thanks.

Comment: you probably signed the certificate with a wrong / inaccurate url

Comment: Look at subject name in the certificate - should be clear what the issue is... Note that `localhost` probably not going to work anyway as it is generally special case for IP - you may need hosts file entry or use machine name for the cert...